# Amsart table of contents long lines are not aligned left

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, amsart

Short question: I noticed that using amsart, after the line break in a long section header in the table of contents, the second line is centered, and I would like it being aligned left. Any idea how I can fix this?

Edit: When trying to recreate the situation, it actually worked fine on the section header 3, which was not working in my project, but not on the sub subsection 3.1.1; here you can still see that the second line is not aligned correctly.
[image]

and the code

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Preliminaries}

\section{Sobolev Spaces}

\section{Variational Formulation of Elliptic Boundary-Value Problems of Second Order}

\subsection{The variational formulation}

\subsubsection{Weak solutions of boundary-value problem with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary solutions}\hfill

\subsubsection{Inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions}\hfill 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show a full but minimal example. Then everyone known what you are talking about and it is easier to recommend solutions.

Comment: @John Thanks for taking the time to edit your post, but instead of an image, please add a short, but compilable test document which we can use to recreate the problem.